# When is wp_loaded initiated only with admin or only when user enters the site or both?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-load.php

When is `wp_loaded` initiated?

Im trying to add function that downloads a big file for the plugin DB, and I need it to be executed whenever user/admin/unknown user get in the frontend, after the site is fully loaded, so that it would not be any delay with the site speed, and user experience.

I use this script:

```
// add update check when admin login
if (is_admin()) {
    function wp_plugin_update() {
            include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'wp-plugin-update.php');
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_shabbat_update' );
}
// add update check when user enter the site after footer loaded
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function wp_plugin_update() {
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'wp-plugin-update.php');
        }
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wp_plugin_update' );
}
```

Can I only use this and it will work with admin and when user enter the site? :

```
function wp_plugin_update() {
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'wp-plugin-update.php');
        }
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wp_plugin_update' );
```

Comment: `wp_loaded` action is triggered in admin and in frontend no matter what user visits the site, it is triggered even for guest users. I think you are falling into a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you are trying to do? Also, you are wrong when you connect `is_admin()` function and "check when admin login". `is_admin()` checks if the user is in the administration section of the site (wp-admin) no matter what roles the user has assigned.

Comment: @cybmeta hi, thank u for the comment, that what i was looking for "wp_loaded action is triggered in admin and in frontend no matter what user visits the site"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) fires for both the front-end and admin section of the site.

> This action hook is fired once WordPress, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.

Since you're checking for plugin updates, it might be best to hook into [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) instead of [`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) -- assuming you want to know if a [`user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) is logged in and viewing the [admin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) section of the site.

```
function wpse_20160114_admin_init_update_plugin() {

    // don't run on ajax calls
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
       return;
    }

    // only administrators can trigger this event
    if(is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('manage_options')) 
    {
        @include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'wp-plugin-update.php');
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_20160114_admin_init_update_plugin');
```

In the case that you want to run on the front-end for all users

```
function wpse_20160114_update_plugin() {

    // don't run on ajax calls
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return;
    }

    // only run on front-end
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'wp-plugin-update.php');
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'wpse_20160114_update_plugin');
```

---

As far as my tests are concerned, [`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) fires after [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) but before [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init).

Front-End

- [ `init` ]
- [ `widgets_init` ]
- [ `wp_loaded` ]

Admin

- [ `init` ]
- [ `widgets_init` ]
- [ `wp_loaded` ]
- [ `admin_menu` ]
- [ `admin_init` ]

---

[image]

Comment: *Because wp_loaded fires after admin_init*  Not true

Comment: tx for the detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

`wp_loaded` runs front end and back end regardless of user and page. Whenever a page is requested `wp_loaded` will run.

Typically, by the time `wp_loaded` executes, Wordpress is done loading and it is also the first hook available to use after WordPress is fully loaded. Users have already being validated/authenticated (*users was already authenticated on `init`, this happens front end and back end*) by this time, so that data is already availble.

You should look at the [action hook execution sequence](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for both front end and back end actions and determine which hook will be best for the specific application you need to run. Note that certain actions like `init` and `wp_loaded` executes on both front end and back end, so you would need to do the `is_admin()` check to specifically target the front end or back end according to your needs.

Sorry that I cannot be more specific, but your question is lacking very specific info, but in general you would do something like the following on `wp_loaded` on the front end only

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function ()
{
    if ( !is_admin() ) { // Only target the front end
        // Do what you need to do
    }
});
```

Comment: tx for ur answer

Answer (score 1):

`wp_loaded` is being triggered after the core initialization is done and before any output is emitted. user authentication is also done at this stage.

In general, you will need to hook on it, or earlier hooks, only if you need to change any of the globals initiated by core before any actual output is done. If you are interested only in changing the output this hook is too early and you better find a more specialized hook that is triggered later. For admin it can be `admin_init` while for front-end it can be `template_redirect` which is triggered when wordpress decides which template to use or `wp_head` that is (almost) the first hook that is triggered as part of the front-end output itself.

Comment: tx for ur answer